Op amp as a comparator output turning partially high when it's supposed to be low
I'm using an AD823 op amp, as a comparator as part of a feedback loop in a boost converter. Although the boost converter and feedback portion functions as desired, the problem is when I check the 13 V PWM waveform on the switching MOSFET: when the feedback kicks in, the output of the PWM becomes distorted.
The waveform pictured is from the node "test", but the node "FB" exhibits the exact same behavior




the output of the PWM becomes distorted

Yes it will.
You are trying to implement control by removing power to the transistor (Q3) that buffers the fixed duty cycle pulses that feed the gate of the MOSFET (M1). So, when the op-amp tries to remove power from Q3 via its collector, the oscillator signal still passes through via base to emitter with maybe a 0.7 volt drop (due to the base-emitter junction acting like a diode).

However, if it still works acceptably, I've seen worse designs. I will also add this; your circuit does not use PWM i.e. there is no circuit evidence of a variable duty cycle.

I originally used two 555 timers for the square wave and feedback portion (one in astable and one in mono) but ended up swapping them due to my professor saying I did not need two oscillators. I ended up with this design for the square wave, since I have 2n3904's but I don't currently have any 555's. Out of curiousity, how would you go about designing the square wave and feedback portion? I agree that my solution is rather inelegant and would like to learn more from someone more experienced.

@MXVG I highly recommend that to get the best answer from this site, you raise a new post and open up the question to the floor (rather than relying on limited information that I can provide in comments). After all, this is a Q and A site and, what you ask seems a proper question.

You can avoid this issue (caused by the E-B diode of Q3) by replacing Q3 with a 2N7000 or similar n-channel MOSFET.
C4 is not necessary that I see (at least from a brief look).

I see, yes that makes sense, presumably a mosfet would prevent this as there's no current from gate to source like the diode in the base-emitter junction. Thank you! I added C4 because I was getting ringing in output of the Q3 emitter, I'm not sure why this works, I just copied this technique from the TA in one of the labs for my classes
